# How to check where a Panel's Children come from?

Tags: wpf, panel, itemscontrol

I created a custom [`Panel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx), within which I need to check whether its `Children` are managed by manipulating the collection manually, or whether the panel is used as `ItemsPanel` for an `ItemsControl`.

This to prevent the following exception from being thrown when trying to manipulate `Children`.

> Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as
>   ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for
>   Panel.

How can I differentiate between the two different usages of the panel?

Comment: Can I ask why you are modifying the collection of children? Isn't the point of a **Panel** purely to layout its children by measuring and arranging them?

Comment: @StevenRands That is a fair question, and I'm not fully certain it is a good idea yet either. Regardless, the scenario is I added the ability of specifying 'factories' to the panel ([search for 'LabelFactories' here](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.PresentationFramework/Windows/Controls/AxesPanel.cs)) which manage recurrent labels which need to be displayed on the panel. When the panel is unloaded, I need to remove the labels added by the factories, but only when factories are used (as opposed to `ItemsSource`).

Comment: OK, I see. I've used the panel's `OnRender` method to dynamically draw stuff like this in the past. It does have the drawback though that anything "rendered" in this way will appear _behind_ all of the children. Nevertheless there are situations where the approach is still useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Panel's `IsItemsHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.isitemshost(v=vs.110).aspx) property can be used to check whether the Panel *"is a container for user interface (UI) items that are generated by an ItemsControl"*.

This property can be set manually when creating an `ItemsControl` template, but also seems to be set to true when using an [`ItemsPresenter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemspresenter(v=vs.110).aspx) and specifying the panel using [`ItemsControl`'s `ItemsPanel` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx).